# Cutting a 3d shape using a plane

Tags: 3d, shapes, cut, plane

I have a shape made of triangles in 3d. The shape is intersecting a plane. I would like to make the plane cut the shape, so to slice the intersecting triangles and return the (new) triangles making up the newly formed (cut) shape. So extra triangles will have to be generated to facilitate for the new edge.

Could anyone please point me to some resources on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `intersect3D_SegmentPlane()` from the following source http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0104/algorithm_0104B.htm for each triangle edge.